# PhoneGap iPhone: how to pass back an array of JSON objects using the PluginResult API

Tags: iphone, cordova

I need to pass back an array of `JSON` object in the similar to the following way,
From iPhone's plugin to the `JavaScript` side using the Successful callback mechanism on **PhoneGap 1.0.0**.

I have success on passing back 1 single JSON object but cannot find out how to do any array.
Any idea?  Thanks ahead.

```
[ {name: "abc", number: 1234567890}, {name: "xyz", number: 9876543210} ].
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing it back to the JavaScript as an actual JSON string and parsing it there?

```
var onSuccess = function(data) {
    var incomingData = JSON.parse(data);
    // do something with incomingData...
};
```